# How to make work ng-click and $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, angularjs-ng-click

Well, I have some function that invokes via ng-click.
For example, this function set variable `a` to `true`, and after few seconds variable should become `false`.
Function looks like this one:

```
$scope.do = function (){
    $scope.a = true;
    $timeout($scope.a=false,5000);
  }
```

But when I call this function, varibale `a` become `false` immediately, without wating 5 secs.
Am I do everything right ?
Demo on [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9VdiBMzkdq1tonDLN6Bq?p=preview).
How can I achieve "waiting" after click with AngularJS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout) (as well as native javascript `setTimeout`) expects a function as the first argument:

```
$scope.do = function() {
    $scope.a = true;
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.a = false;
    }, 5000);
};
```

This function reference you provide, will then be invoked after timer is up.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Rg82R98gViWJ8YZtJD8z?p=preview

Comment: My fault.
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

This should do

```
$scope.do = function (){
    $scope.a = true;
    $timeout(function(){$scope.a=false},5000);
  }
```